# how to leave 50dp empty space in html?

Tags: html, ios, css, cordova

My doing a mobile webapp, i want to leave a height of 50dp empty at the top of the screen , any ideas ?

i have tried make a div with 50dp height but this did not work

```
<div style="display:inline-block; height:20px width: 70px">My Text Here</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of solutions, depending on what you are trying to achieve. Also, I would consider moving your styles from being inline with the HTML to an external stylesheet, as this follows best practice and would help your styles be more modular/reusable.

Margin: `.inner-element { margin-top: 50px; }`

Positioning `.inner-element { position: relative; top: 50px; }`

Padding `.container-element { padding-top: 50px; }`